# Decoding special characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, character

How can I, using Javascript, turn this:

```
RUA CALLOUSTE GULBENKIAN  N.\XBA\ 42 3\XBA\ ESQ
```

into this:

```
RUA CALLOUSTE GULBENKIAN  N.º 42 3º ESQ
```

Is there some method that does this? Because otherwise I would have to predict all the special characters that could appear to replace them.

**EDIT:**

Tried using `String(text)` after lower-casing the x and it still doesn't decode the character. Anyone knows any other way?

Comment: Is it only the `º` character you are trying to decode? Or is it all encoded characters?

Comment: All of them, otherwise I would just replace it with replace().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String()` to do so, however you'll need to lowercase the X in the escapes (resulting in `\xBA`)

Example code (tested in Chrome dev console):

```
> String('RUA CALLOUSTE GULBENKIAN  N.\xBA\ 42 3\xBA ESQ');
< "RUA CALLOUSTE GULBENKIAN  N.º 42 3º ESQ"
```

[Source (MDN, last one in the table)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

Comment: @AndréSilva It should, yes.

Comment: nice and clean solution ;)

Comment: It is returning false to me. Edited question with code snippet.

Comment: @AndréSilva You could just use `texto.replace(/\\X([0-9A-F]{2})/, '\\x$1')`

Comment: If I do it like this `new String('RUA CALLOUSTE GULBENKIAN  N.\xBA\ 42 3\xBA ESQ')` it works but if I use a variable like this `new String(variable)` that contains the same it stops working. Do you know what may be issue?